# How to fix limited inter instance communication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ipc

We have one main instance running a faye server running on port X.

We then on command start arbitrary number of spot instances for jobs.

Each spot instance runs a docker container and each container runs a faye client that connects to main instance faye server on port X.

Currently, only first 3 of the started spot instance's faye client can connect to main instance faye server. Those started after first 3 cannot connect.

We can fix this by editing security group so all ips (0.0.0.0/0) can access port X but we don't want to do that.

The private ips of the instances all start with 172.31.x.x so we've tried adding in Security group 172.0.0.0/8 and 172.31.0.0/24 and tried going from 172.31.0.0 /32 down to /1 (the x.x.x.x changes with change to /n) but same limitation is still there.

Nothing in the other security groups is using 172.x.x.x so it's not being limited by that.

What should have been the correct CIDR to use in the security group to only allow ip starting with 172.31?

Is there another setting maybe that's limiting the number of spot instance faye clients able to connect to main spot instance's faye server?

Update:

Moved update into an answer post.

Comment: is it required to access by ip? there is another way to achieve this by just using the docker network

Comment: @chrism can you try giving the cidr block for the whole vpc once. 
If it works then narrow it down to maybe the subnet cidr range where all these instances are

Answer (score 0):

We've solved the problem.

We were (and have been) using the public ip of main instance to connect to it from the spot instances. Using the private ip of main instance and adding 172.31.16.0/20 to Security Group (found VPC dashboard and saw the subnets used by spot instances) made it work.